# accessing paged data source from itemDataBound in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater, custompaging

I've bound my repeater to a PagedDataSource and I want to get the PagedCount from the ItemDataBound event. I've tried a few things and it's not working. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably been resolved, but here goes.

You want to use this value when binding the footer element for paging, right?
You can access the datasource on databound.

```
List<object> dataSource = repeater.DataSource as List<object>;
```

The DataSource will be null, though, after all the items have been bound.

When binding the buttons or links, you can set the page numbers in `button.CommandArgument` and set `button.CommandName = "next"`, for example.
Then ofcourse add the `OnItemCommand` stuff.